# multiple json in one asyncktask is good or multiple asyncktask with diffrent json is good

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am developing an android app where is more than 10 api my app is going to slow  I am using 10 asyncktask which is sending 1 api per asyncktask. So, I am thinking I will call 1 asynktask and  call 10 Json in 1 asyncktask so can anyone tell me which is the right approach?

Comment: You can run multiple `AsyncTasks` in parallel with `API =>11` or you can use `ThreadExecutor`.

Comment: how to use tread executer

Answer (score 0):

Call other api calling mediums, tools like
1) Retrofit
2) Volley

These has major improvement on performance of the app

Comment: so retrofit is fast or volley and if I want cancle any time which  is the best

Comment: I prefer retrofit because its light, flexible and fast